# Extract email address from Google account

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-api

I'm working on a website where the client has asked for an option to allow signup/login using Google and Facebook accounts. How can I extract the email address from a user's Google profile for storing in database?

Here is my code. The problem is that I am not getting the user profile completely. Instead, I am receiving just user name.

```
try
{
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="
         + access_token;

     string outputData = client.DownloadString(urlProfile);

     GoogleUserOutputData serStatus =
         JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserOutputData>(outputData);

     if (serStatus != null)
     {
         return serStatus;
         // You will get the user information here.
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     //catching the exception
 }

 return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to receive data (email, etc.) in JavaScript. At the end it shows an alert with data. (You can store this data in a database.) It's a complete working example with a Google button.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Demo: Getting an email address using the Google+ Sign-in button</title>
    <!-- Include the API client and Google+ client. -->
    <script src = "https://plus.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Container with the Sign-In button. -->
    <div id="gConnect" class="button">
      <button class="g-signin"
          data-scope="email"
          data-clientid="Your_Client_ID"
          data-callback="onSignInCallback"
          data-theme="dark"
          data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
      </button>
      <!-- Textarea for outputting data -->
      <div id="response" class="hide">
        <textarea id="responseContainer" style="width:100%; height:150px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>

  <script>
  /**
   * Handler for the signin callback triggered after the user selects an account.
   */
      function onSignInCallback(resp) {

    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', apiClientLoaded);
  }

  /**
   * Sets up an API call after the Google API client loads.
   */
      function apiClientLoaded() {

    gapi.client.plus.people.get({userId: 'me'}).execute(handleEmailResponse);
  }

  /**
   * Response callback for when the API client receives a response.
   *
   * @param resp The API response object with the user email and profile information.
   */
  function handleEmailResponse(resp) {
      var primaryEmail;
      var name;
      var gender;

    for (var i=0; i < resp.emails.length; i++) {
        if (resp.emails[i].type === 'account')
            primaryEmail = resp.emails[i].value;
        if (resp.displayName != null)
            name = resp.displayName;
        gender = resp.gender;
    }
    document.getElementById('responseContainer').value = 'Primary email: ' +
          primaryEmail + '\n\nFull Response:\n' + JSON.stringify(resp);
      ShowAlert("Email: "+primaryEmail +" "+"Name: "+ resp.displayName +" "+"Gender: "+gender);
  }

  </script>

</html>
```

For further information and detail you can (should) read this link:
[Getting people and profile information](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But i was still getting one error ,it was not getting the response then i came up with solution "By enabling the Google+ API" in my dashboard. If someone is facing the problem please do enable your Google+ API in your google developer account. https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library?pli=1

Comment: @MuhammadMohsan I accepted your enhancement to the answer by Vinod kumar G, since presumably you lifted additional relevant code from the Google reference documentation. Generally, however, you should not do this. Instead, you should post your *own* answer. Alternatively, as a courtesy, after making a substantial edit, you can leave a comment on the answer asking the individual who posted it to roll back your edit if they do not approve it. But please don't do this very often.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is the key; please check it completely.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

<script>
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I accepted the enhancement by @MuhammadMohsan. Please roll back the edit if you do not approve it.